# Background image will not show up in IE8 or below but works in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a project that has a background image that will not show in IE unless you put a space between the ) and no repeat. When you put that space it does show but is distorted. This background image works in both Firefox and Chrome.

Live link: http://www.mastisolcostanalysis.com/survey

CSS:

```
#app-wrapper{
width: 1024px;
height: 768px;
min-height:100%;
margin: 0px auto;
/*margin-top: -384px;
position: relative;
top: 50%;*/
text-align: left;
background: url(../img/ui-frame.png)no-repeat;
overflow: hidden; 
background-size: 100%;
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Forgot to mention that it does NOT show up in IE8 or lower.

Comment: IE8 does not support CSS `background-size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem is the background image it's a problem with the size.  It's 2048 x 1536.

http://www.mastisolcostanalysis.com/img/ui-frame.png

You should resize it to be 1024 x 768 as you defined on #app-wrapper.

IE8 can't scale images the way modern browsers do.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse...but its still the same. Shows up but does not look the same, looks distorted. See screenshots in this thread

Comment: Dude, your awesome. That was exactly it. I resized and it looks great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
background: url('../img/ui-frame.png') no-repeat;
```

Comment: Thank you, its now showing up but is distorted. Here's a screenshot of Chrome on the left and IE on the right: http://www.mastisolcostanalysis.com/screenshot/screenshot01.png

Comment: @DarrellW well u gotta deal with that..after all its "IE".

Comment: Yeah, it definitely is "IE"

Answer (score 0):

Put your background image in an image tag () and add a class to it. Add this tag right above the #app-wrapper element in the HTML structure. Style the image tag like this:

```
img.bg { 
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I added that but can you explain putting the image in an image tag() ? It needs to be the background of the wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like you have significant issues with the way your website is setup.  When I started to edit the CSS via the Web Developer extension in FF I noticed you just have content stacked ontop of eachother absolute positioned and also z-indexed like crazy.  Why are these not separate pages?  I really think a lot of your issues have to deal with the amount of absolute positioning and z-indexing that you have going on.

I noticed as I messed with the background positioning and whatnot that something was off by the way it was handling things.

I would honestly break out each one of those content sections into their own pages, I think that alone will help you point the compass in the right direction as to why you are having your IE issues.

Also, I would highly suggest scaling that image down yourself in photoshop or something similar.  It's full size is 2048x1536 yet you are trying to force it to be 1024x768.  That could also be leading to a lot of your issues.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, this works in Chrome and Firefox but distort in IE8 still. Here's the screenshot http://www.mastisolcostanalysis.com/screenshot/screenshot02.png

Comment: Thanks. That bit of code worked along with resizing the background image. I agree, separate pages. We got an outside developer that made it all one page.

Answer (score 0):

This site helps me for IE8 and works well

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/